# Parsing a JSON file to be used as a menu "tree" in a list view in Android

Tags: android, json, listview

I have a local JSON file in my project currently and would like to parse it into an array and then use this array to make clickable list items to create a sort of menu. A screenshot of an example of this is below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeSnA.png

I know how to create this from an array, the issue I am having is parsing what I need into an array so I can create this list view. Here is a sample of my JSON.

```
{
    "Weapons":
    {
        "Ranged":
        [
            {
                "name": "Bow",
                "desc" : "This is a bow"
            },
            {
                "name": "Crossbow",
                "desc" : "This is a crossbow"
            }

        ],
        "Melee":
        [
            {
                "name" : "Machete",
                "desc" : "This is a machete"
            }
        ]
    },

    "Armor":
    {
        "Metal":
        [
            {
                "name": "Metal Chest Plate",
                "desc": "This is a metal chest plate"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I would like to have a menu starting with "weapons" and "armor". From there, if you were to click on "Weapons", you would then see a new menu giving you the option of either "Ranged" or "Melee". Then from "Ranged" you would have either "Bow" or "Crossbow". Could someone assist me with parsing this to an array so I can accomplish this? I've been struggling with this for several days. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use "JSON Simple" library for your task.
Some info about [JSON Simple](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple/1.1.1) here

```
    public static final String LOT_JSON_CAR = "car";
    public static final String LOT_JSON_PRICE = "price";
    public static final String LOT_JSON_LOTS = "lots";

    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject jsonObject;
    try {
        jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(/* your json here */);
        JSONArray jsonLotsArray = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get(LOT_JSON_LOTS);
        Iterator<JSONObject> iterator = jsonLotsArray.iterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            JSONObject jsonLot = iterator.next();
            JSONObject jsonCar = (JSONObject) jsonLot.get(LOT_JSON_CAR);
            JSONObject jsonUser = (JSONObject) jsonCar.get(CAR_JSON_USER);
        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // some code here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) to deserialize the json text into your Java class.  From there, you can use the class with your adapter of choice to create the menu (or iterate over it if you are creating a custom menu, I suppose).

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this as follows :

Create a POJO from your json structure. It can be done very easily from [here](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

Set Source type to JSON, annotation style to None. 
This tool will help you in creating the model class with complete hierarchy.

After this, you can use GSON to deserialize your json into java objects. GSON does this step as follows :

```
Gson menu= new Gson();
menu.fromJson(receivedJsonFromBackend, YOURMODELCLASS.class)
```

After that you can just play with the menu object like menu.getName, menu.getDesc etc.